# How to display real numbers with a desired number of decimal places when viewing an attribute table?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, geopackage

At 3.18.3, is there a way to **display** Geopackage *real* attribute values in an attribute table (with table view) with a user-specified number of decimal places, while maintaining the data's internal precision?

For example, I may wish to display the records in a *real* field with two decimal places as 0.77, yet maintain its internal value of 0.7741935483870968.

Maintaining the internal value preserves future flexibility: some day I might have to perform a calculation that requires the full number of decimal places, or display the value with a different number of decimal places, for example 0.77419.

Perhaps related, when creating a real field using the field calculator, the *output field length* and *precision* options are greyed out:

[image]

I've searched SE for an answer, and also gone through the *Settings > Options...* with no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have not found a way to specify a format to use for display in the same sense as is possible in, say, Excel (or other spreadsheets).

If you are comfortable to have the values read-only, there is a work around.
Create a shadow virtual field like `"test_example_"` (note trailing _) and define it using the expression `round("test_example",5)` (or whatever number of digits).
Then hide `"test_example"` in the attribute table and show only `"test_example_"`.

Comment: Your solution works.  I'm still curious why the Output Field Length and Precision options are greyed out (highlighted in the OP), so I'll ask that in a separate question.